# Why replace char doesn't work for Kotlin while calling regular replace on char function

Tags: kotlin

I am calling `replace()` on a string to change the chars but for some reason it does not change it.

```
 var result = "Hi!"
 result.replace('i','z')
```

In logs I still see `Hi!`

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable. When you call `replace`, the function returns a new String instance. You'll have to assign the result to something if you want to use it elsewhere.

```
var result = "Hi!"
result = result.replace('i','z')
```